# consulta del ultimo registro y el ultimo en el populate

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, moongose

Hola tengo una consulta enlazada con otra colección, y hago referencia a la misma a través de un populate, pero quiero tener el ultimo registro del find y el ultimo registro de ese usuario en la tabla populate (pago), estoy comenzando y no se si se pueda acá el código y disculpen los errores..

```
var promocionesList = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    Promociones.find({
        "fechafinPromo": {
            $lt: hoy
        }


    }, function (err, promociones) {
        if (promociones) {
            resolve(promociones);

        } else {
            reject('ocurrio un problema intentalo nuevamente')
        }
    }).populate('pagos')
    .sort({createdAt:-1}).limit(1);
})
```

quisiera ver si sepuede el ultimo en la coleccion, "promociones" y el ultimo en la coleccion pago, no se si se pueda...gracias

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con un proceso de agregación, pero necesito ver la estructura de los datos, al menos el esquema de Promociones y Pagos para ver la forma en que estás creando la referencia. Saludos